# How do I specify 2 foreign keys in a model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like to be able to access current_users conversation with ease. 
E.G.

```
current_user.conversations
```

The thing is the current user can either be a sender or recipient (sender_id or recipient_id)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :conversations, :foreign_key => "sender_id"
```

This works but there are times when a sender is a recipient or say for example someone has sen t someone 10 messages as a sender and the recipient hasn't replied to any but still a conversation exists in the database for them.

If I was logged in as that user and typed current_user.conversations nothing would come up because the foreign key specified in the user model is sender_id. Isn't there a way to specify both? Like using "OR" in sql?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do *exactly* what you want, but there are a few alternate approaches you may want to consider:

1) Splitting it up into two relationships, sent_conversations and received_conversations, and then you can define a method which combines them.

2) Adding a new class method that does some custom SQL:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def conversations
    Conversation.where("sender_id = :id OR receiver_id = :id", id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Just added a class method to the conversations model, similar to what you done in example number 2.

Comment: Just realized my code had a few bugs in it, hopefully that didn't throw you off too much :) They are fixed now.